# How do I set every selectable li to a different color on click? (JQuery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

This a sample of the script I have so far.
The default behavior once an `<li>` is selected, is to change the background color to orange (also default). My goal is to have every `<li>` changing to a different color when selected.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

 <style>
.st0{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
#selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
#selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
#selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; width: 85px;}
</style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
  $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
});

$( "#btn1" ).click( function(event, ui) {
  // code here is too long to include
} ); 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ol id = "selectable">
    <li id = "btn1" class="ui-widget-content">Office #1</li> 
    <li id = "btn2" class="ui-widget-content">Office #2</li> 
    <li id = "btn3" class="ui-widget-content">Office #3</li> 
    <li id = "btn4" class="ui-widget-content">Office #4</li>     
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: used "<li>" tags in the question which automatically turned to bullet points. Apologies for the rookie mistake. I'm new to programming and this is my first post!

Comment: Do you have specific colors in mind and will you always only have four buttons?

Comment: Specific colors don't matter. As long as each button has a unique color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about getting a random number (between 0 to 255) to define a RGB color?
It doesn't *ensure* the color will be unique... But...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( "#selectable" ).selectable();

  $("li").on("mousedown",function(){
    var r = parseInt(Math.random()*255);
    var g = parseInt(Math.random()*255);
    var b = parseInt(Math.random()*255);

    console.log("rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")");
    $(this).css({"background-color":"rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")"})
  });

});
```

```css
.st0{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
#selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
#selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
#selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; width: 85px;}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ol id = "selectable">
  <li id = "btn1" class="ui-widget-content">Office #1</li> 
  <li id = "btn2" class="ui-widget-content">Office #2</li> 
  <li id = "btn3" class="ui-widget-content">Office #3</li> 
  <li id = "btn4" class="ui-widget-content">Office #4</li>     
</ol>
```

By the way, the `click` event is prevented by `.selectable()`, so I used `mousedown`.

Comment: That's great, but how do you revert the button back to original state?

Comment: I was just curious, I'm gonna give it a try, but I'm sure I will fail lol..

Comment: @almostabeginner: You could add a "reset" button... And set all `li` background-color to [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)... Like `$("#reset").on("click", function(){$("li").css({"background-color":"initial"});)`

Comment: I meant when button1 is clicked -> selected -> selected color is applied to button1, but when button2 is clicked, then button1 shouldn't continue to have selected color applied to it. It should revert back to original non-selected color, which is white.

Comment: `$("li").css({"background-color":"initial"});` resets all `li` colors to initial... So use it right before `$(this).css({"background-color":"rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")"});` for the behavior you ask for.

Comment: Thanks! Louys i wasted a day trying to fix this using click. It works perfectly with mouse down.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the `<li>` elements share a class, you could just target that class and use .addClass() to give them the .ui-selected class.

`$('.ui-widget-content').addClass('.ui-selected');`

Comment: If I go with the class solution, how would I set each to a different color? How would that work when unselecting/selecting a different button? Does it revert to it's original state?